# ¿Cómo puedo guardar los registros de una tabla html en una BD?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo una tabla HTML que lleno dinámicamente con una tabla de una BD, a cada fila que devuelve le agrego un *input text* para que agregue cierta información para cada fila, una fila no tiene nada que ver con las demás, actualmente ya le he colocado nombre diferente a cada input de la tabla

¿Cómo puedo hacer para guardar en mi BD esos input y en general los registros de la tabla?

Comment: Deberías añadir código. Si supiste cargar desde una BD no debería ser mayor problema guardar ya que solo deberias hacer referencia a tus ID de input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saludos

creo que te lo estas complicando mucho, pienso que si haces una tabla y luego la recorres con javascript; luego usando ajax y php puedes procesar fila por fila y guardar tu tabla

```
  var t = document.getElementById("trip-table"); //una tabla con id 
  var trs = t.getElementsByClassName("idServicio"); // cada row tiene clase
  for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) 
  { 
     var id = trs[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
     // AJAX $.ajax({ 
           dataType:"json", 
           type: "GET", 
           url: "procesarFila.php", 
           data: {id:id}, 
           success: function(data) { 
           //hacer algo luego de procesar 
           });
}
```

Comment: ¿Como lo haría, tienes un ejemplo?, lo que pasa que tengo un botón para procesar toda la tabla

Comment: deja pongo el codigo en la respuesta es un codigo para recorrer una tabla en javascript

Comment: revisa,  si te fijas yo recorro puros tr pero tu podrias incluso recorrer cada td, solo ajusta a lo que necesites

Comment: si tengo 5 campos tendría que hacer 5 ciclos for?

Comment: si exacto serian 5

Answer (score 0):

tu tabla sería un gran formulario, y lo procesas como cualquier formulario

imagina el html asi

```
<form action="x.php" method="get">
<table>
  <tr><td>algo 1 </td><td><input name="entrada[0]"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>algo 2 </td><td><input name="entrada[1]"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

cuando procesas el formulario $_REQUEST['entrada'] te va a entregar un array en

```
array(
  0 => 'lo que venia en la primera fila',
  1 => 'lo que ingresaron en la segunda'
)
```

los inserts o updates en la base de datos lo puedes hacer en un foreach

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['entrada'] as $k => $v )
{
  // el $v contiene lo que se ingreso asi que hay que sanitizarlo por 
  // sql injections
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO table values (fila,valor) VALUES ('.$k.',"',$v,'")';
  // procesar el sql
}
```

Comment: pero se insertaría en la BD como una sola fila si lo proceso asi

Comment: no, porque es un cliclo, si tienes 10 filas en tu tabla, se hará 10 veces y serán 10 inserts

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco complejo lo que tratas de hacer, afortunadamente hay componentes que hacen exactamente lo que pides, te invito a probar [datatables](https://datatables.net/), para editar la tabla [aquí](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)